# pip will not install in my command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, module, pip, pycharm

i am using python. python version 3.8 and currently trying to run modules. inside my command prompt, whenever i try to use any command, for pip that is. it gives and error Import Error: No module named pip. i am still quite new to programming in fact i am learning python as my first language. Anyways the error is preventing me from using any modules as i cant install them. pip is simply not working. How can i solve this.
I have tried to reinstall pip directory. the error is still the same.

Comment: You aren't doing `import pip` in your python code are you?

Comment: No, I am not. i am using the import on modules

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Ubuntu, pip is a separate package: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/.  Also note the executable in this case is named pip3.

If you're on a different distro, try looking in your package manager for a python3-pip package.

Comment: The term `command prompt` used in text of questioner and the tag `cmd` are indications that the questioner uses Windows as operating system. And the questioner has most likely not read the documentations of [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) at all which is the real problem here.